# Having trouble insert data from beautifulsoup4 into a sqlite3 db

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm unable to get my sqlite3 db to populate with any information despite being able to pull all the information into a .csv file. I'm fairly new to sqlite3, but have been trying to get this to work for the past few days unsuccessfully. This code is from me watching a youtube video on using beautifulsoup4 to export results to a csv.

It allows me to create the desired columns in sqlite3, but doesn't populate it with the information that I've isolated with beautifulsoup4. I'm not sure if I'm properly calling the information into sqlite3. I've tried a variety of ways to import the data, but none have been successful.

```
    #Make a request to the ebay.com get a page
#collect data from each detail page
#collect all links to detail pages of each product
# write scraped data to a csv file

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sqlite3


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server Responded', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    return soup
    #print(response.ok)
    #print(response.status_code)


def get_detail_data(soup):
    #title
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').get_text().replace('Details about', '').strip()   
    except:
        title = ''
    #price 
    try:
        price = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').get_text()    
    except:
        price = ''
    #department    
    try:
        department = soup.find('span', itemprop="name").text.strip().split(' ')
    except:
        department = ''
    #seller   
    try:
        seller = soup.find('span', class_='mbg-nw').get_text()
    except:
        seller = ''
        
#Having difficulty pulling the "data" into my db
    data = {
        'title':title,
        'price': price,
        'department': department,
        'seller': seller
    }
    
    return data

def get_index_data(soup):

    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')

    except:
        links = []

    urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]
    return urls

#disabled csv function below
#def write_csv(data, url):

    #with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
      #  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

      #  row = [data['title'], data['price'], data['seller'], data['department'], url]
       # writer.writerow(row)
        
def main():
    url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=colonel+blade+-coon&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=colonel+blade'
    

    product = get_index_data(get_page(url))

    for link in product:
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
        write_csv(data, link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    
    #having difficulty importing beautifulsoup data into db
conn =sqlite3.connect("ultimate_ebay_scraper4.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''drop table if exists ultimate_ebay_scraper4''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ultimate_ebay_scraper4(title TEXT, price TEXT, seller TEXT, department TEXT, url TEXT)''')

conn.execute("""INSERT INTO ultimate_ebay_scraper4(title, price, seller, department, url)VALUES(data['title'], data['price'], data['seller'], data['department'], url)""")
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
connector.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you want to reference your data variable in the insert query? Then you'll want to parameterize the execute call

Refer the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

```
execute("INSERT... VALUES(?, ...)",  (data['title'],... ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the following line seems to be in the wrong format for reading the data from your dictionary:

```
conn.execute("""INSERT INTO ultimate_ebay_scraper4(title, price, seller, department, url)VALUES(data['title'], data['price'], data['seller'], data['department'], url)""")
```

Try something like this:

```
cur.execute("insert into ultimate_ebay_scraper4(title, price, seller, department, url) values (?, ?,?,?,?)", (data['title'], data['price'],data['seller'],data['department'],url ))
```

You will need to test, but I expect you get a string literal of the data dictionary instead of the value itself.

Also, I expect the data variable is going out of scope by the time you are attempting to insert it.  Create a function called insert_data(...) and place it in the loop like so:

```
for link in product:
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
        write_csv(data, link)
        insert_data(data) # something like this
```